# renderCell from Mui DataGrid not rendering conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a simple setup for my Mui DataGrid. The issue I have though, is that `renderCell` isn't rendering my elements conditionally.

[image]

It should show per default an `EditIcon` button (the pencil) and as soon as I click on it, it should call `fetchSomething` - which it does - and switch to the Mui `CircularProgress` element by setting `isLoading` to true but the CircularProgress element is never displayed.

I tested quickly via a `useEffect` to see if the state changes and it does change from false to true then again to false but the `CircularProgress` is nowhere to be seen.

Am I having issues with ids? Any way to solve this?

```
const Component = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const fetchSomething = (event) => {

        setIsLoading(true);

        fetch(event.id)
         .then(() => doSmth())
         .catch((error) => console.log(error))
         .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    };


    const usersTableColumns = [
            {
                field: 'id',
                headerName: 'ID',
                width: 200,
                flex: 1,
            },
            {
                field: 'username',
                headerName: 'USER NAME',
                width: 170,
                flex: 1,
            },
            {
                field: 'action',
                headerName: 'Edit',
                sortable: false,
                renderCell: (params) => (isLoading ? <CircularProgress size={30} /> : (
                    <EditIcon onClick={fetchSomething} />
                )),
            },
    ];

    return(
        <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={usersTableColumns}/>
    );
}
```

**EDIT**
According to the logic above all pencils should become spinners as soon as I click on one of them, so I tried adding dynamically the `ids` to the state and checking for a certain `id` when displaying `CircularProgress` but it seems like the state updates just don't show up for `renderCell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this the solution is very simple. It took me a bit but I got it.

You need to export the content of `renderCell` into a new component and import it. You will also have to put the hook into that component. This will create a component for each row so you will not have any issues with `ids`.

Even then, conditionally rendering the cell would not work anyways.

[image]

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/

```
const Component = ({
    fetchSmth, params,
}) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const doSmth= async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        await fetchSmth(params.row);
        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <Tooltip title='Some title'>
            <IconButton
                variant='contained'
                onClick={(e) => {
                    doSmth(e);
                }}
            >
                {isLoading ? <CircularProgress size={30} /> : <EditIcon />}
            </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
    );
};

export default Component;
```

`renderCell` has just to render this component. You can test this (if your REST call is too fast by throttling your browser in mobile mode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like renderCell doesn't take into account the change of state.

So another option is to add a new parameter in your rows that indicates the loading state.

```
rows = [
    {id: 'row1', isLoading: true},
    {id: 'row2', isLoading: false},
]
```

In your 'fetchSomething' function, you update the row parameter value.

and your renderCell can check this new parameter:

```
renderCell: (params) => (params.row.isLoading ? <CircularProgress size={30} /> : (
                <EditIcon onClick={fetchSomething} />
            )),
```